# Need to copy items of a list to text box

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to create a selection list. When an item on the list is clicked same should be showing in a text box, when another item is clicked even that should be added to text box. I am trying to work out the code below but somehow its not doing its job. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function register_click(num){
document.getElementById('boxclicked').value += num; 

}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<td><ul>

<li id="2" onclick="register_click(1)">List item 1</li>
<li id="3" onclick="register_click(2)">List item 2</li>
<li id="4"onclick="register_click(3)">List Item 3</li>

</ul></td>

<input type='text' size="150%" width="100%" maxlength="" id="boxclicked">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/bBAt2/ However, note that your HTML is not valid - the `ul` is opened inside the `td`, but closed outside the closing `td`.

Comment: IDs must not start with a number. You might want to use another attribute like `data-number`.

Comment: Thank you for the great help friends.. I really appreciate it.. Now, I doubt I haven't explained this clearly enough. what I want some string to be displayed instead of that numbers.I want some text to be displayed in the text box when these items selected, i was wondering if there is a way to display "TEXT" in the text box when clicked.... <li id="2" onclick="register_click(TEXT)">List item 1</li> –

Comment: So you want only TEXT to be displayed? Then if you click an LI that has "More Text" you want the input to only say "More Text"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to do arithmetic, but you're function is actually doing string concatenation. For arithmetic you need to make sure that any 'number' is actually a number and not a string:

```
function register_click(num){
    var box = document.getElementById('boxclicked');
    box.value = box.value || 0
    box.value = parseInt(box.value, 10) + num;
}
```

`box.value` will be undefined on first click, so we make sure that it has a value, even if that value is `0`. [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp) converts a string to a number, we pass `10` to make sure that it does it in base 10.

---

JavaScript is funny sometimes, for instance:

```
"1" + 2 + 3 === "123" // true
2 + 3 + "1" === "51" // true
```

It always tries to coerce types, sometimes this is good, but it can lead to confusion like the above, when it works counter-intuitively. This is what you were running into with your original code. The value of the element was a string, which caused `num` to become a string and be concatenated.

Comment: Thank you for the great help friends.. I really appreciate it.. Now, I doubt I haven't explained this clearly enough....

Comment: Thank you for the great help friends.. I really appreciate it.. Now, I doubt I haven't explained this clearly enough....

Comment: I want some text to be displayed in the text box when these items selected, i was wondering if there is a way to display "TEXT" in the text box when clicked....                                                     <li id="2" onclick="register_click(TEXT)">List item 1</li>